# django error: __init__takes at least 2 arguments 1 given

Tags: django, arguments, typeerror, init

I get the following error:

```
typeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments 1 given`
```

I have these classes:

```
class task(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField('name', max_length=100)
    text=models.TextField('task_text')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class person(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField('name', max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to show the tasks using `render_to_response` as follows:

```
def index(request):
    tass = task.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'tass': task},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But then I get `typeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments 1 given`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the whole error trace? That would help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question fixing some spelling mistakes ("least" is not the same as "last"), and putting the error at the start. I also indented the code a bit more for readability. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is beyond the code you provided, because it should work.
The only mistake is that you should change to `{'tass': tass},`.

Answer (score -1):

The `QueryDict` object must be an input to `RequestContext`. like this:

```
def index(request):
    tass = task.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'tass': task}))
```